# Selecting an aggregate and a column with the same SQL query?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am competing in a SQL database competition, and occasionally I come across problems like

```
SELECT name, MIN(a) 
FROM table
```

According to the answer sheet, the outputted name is indeterminate. However, in a later practice test I am asked to find the exact output of such a query, implying there is a way to determine the returned name value.

The answer keys have a tendency of sometimes being mistaken (too often for comfort). So I ran a query like that one in the W3Schools try-it-yourself box, and got an error. However, I tried it in Codecademy, and it returned the name value associated with the minimal "a" value.

There's so much contradicting information that I don't know what to think!

Comment: According to ANSI/ISO SQL, the above query is invalid and expected to raise an error. However, some vendors do things in their own ways and instead return a (somewhat) arbitrary result.

Comment: If you aggregate you must group non-aggregated columns. That's fundamental iso sql, except where specific products allow the above syntax, which they should not, eg MySql.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule: if you do an aggregation in your `SELECT` clause, and some columns are not aggregated, they should be listed in a `GROUP BY` clause.

As an example, this is what is described for [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY), with my highlight in bold:

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, **it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions** or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.

MySQL also has a neat [help page on the topic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for a reason that I will detail later.

> If **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** is disabled, **a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns** even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns.

As written, MySQL accepts queries where columns are omitted from the `GROUP BY` clause, including the case where all the columns are omitted (= the entire clause is omitted) but **this is an exception to the standard**.
If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option is off, then it will allow such a query to be executed but the value you will get for the non aggregated column `name` will be the first that the database encounters when reading the table.
To my knowledge, MySQL is the only DBMS allowing such queries. I think most people will agree **you should never omit non-aggregated columns** even when the DBMS allows it, because it is non-standard.

To be complete and if you read both quotes carefully, you must have noticed the standard actually allows non-aggregated columns to be omitted in 1 case: **if they are functionally dependent** with the aggregated columns.

My conclusion is that you managed to make your query work on an instance of MySQL (Codecademy) and it failed elsewhere.